# Python 2.7, smart conditioning

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, structure, pretty-print

Here is my case: I got to booleans `a` and `b` and I have function `eatAB()` which can either eat a or b or none.

Here is my problem: `eatAB()` have to be called once and I want it 'smart-and-pretty'. I could do something like this:

```
if not a and not b:
    eatAB()
elif a and not b:
    eatAB(a=a)
elif not a and b:
    eatAB(b=b)
else:
    eatAB(a,b)
```

But For me this one sucks kinda) Is there a prettier or better or smarter or other way to do it? Appreciate your time.

Comment: how does your function 'eat' the booleans?? Show the code for `eatAB` and your desired final output. It might be this logic can go *inside* the function much more neatly

Comment: I'm assuming since you're happy to use the same function for all cases, that it checks whether a or b are None to do it's logic. If so, pass them in as `eatAB(a if a else None, b if b else None)` and get rid of all the conditions.

Comment: @Bilkokuya The `if` checks can also be moved inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is split into two, the top is an updated answer based on new information from the OP - regarding that `eatAB()` is not allowed to be, or able to modified. The second answer is the original answer to how you'd solve this if you have access to modify the function itself.

---

**Updated Answer (where you lack access/permission to modify function)**

As you do not have access to change the function internally, but you do know it's signature `eatAB(a=None,b=None)` we want to follow this logic (from the question):

- If the value we are passing in is truthy (e.g. `True`), we want to pass the value
- If the value is not true, we want to use the default value for the parameter, which is `None`

This can be easily accomplished using the following expression:

```
value if condition else otherValue
```

Which when used when calling the function gives the following:

```
a = False
b = True
eatAB(a if a else None, b if b else None)
# will be the same as calling eatAB(None, True) or eatAB(b=True)
```

Of course, if the values of a and b come from a condition themselves, you can just use that condition. For example:

```
eatAB(someValue if "a" in myDictionary else None, someOtherValue if "b" in myDictionary else None)
```

---

**Original answer (where you have access to modify the function)**:

Not knowing what exactly `eatAB()` does or it's exact signature, the best I can recommend is the following. I'm sure you can adapt this however you need.

The main idea is to move that logic into `eatAB()` as it is the responsibility of the function and not the calling code. Explanation is in the comments:

```
# for parameters a and b to be optional as you have shown, they must have a default value
# While it's standard to use None to denote the parameter is optional, the use case shown in the question has default values where a or b are False - so we will use that here.
def eatAB(a=False, b=False):
    # check if the parameters are truthy (e.g. True), in which case you would have passed them in as shown in the question.
    if a:
        # do some logic here for when a was a truthy value
    if b:
        # do some logic here for when b was a truthy value
    # what exactly the eatAB function I cannot guess, but using this setup you will have the same logic as wanted in the question - without the confusing conditional block each time you call it.

# function can then be called easily, there is no need for checking parameters
eatAB(someValue, someOtherValue)
```

Thanks to Chris_Rands for the improved suggestion.

Comment: Hey, I guess I need to provide a little more details:

Comment: Actual task is this: we have dictionary dictionary = {}, which may or may not contain key 'a' or 'b'. we are not allowed to modify 'eatAB()' inside of it function 'eatAB()' is like this: 'eatAB(a=None, b=None): ....'. And 'eatAB()' takes values of "dictionary['a']" and "dictionary['b']", we have to just make sure it doesn't raise KeyError and eatAB() don't have to be called more than once. So the problem is checking key a or b in dictionary and then passing it inside eatAB(). Sorry for not showing full question before, thought can make it work with booleans alone. Thank you

Comment: @ChynaJake In future, please clarify any and all contraints in the question - otherwise you waste the answerer's time and effort trying to help. I have updated the answer to include the new information you've added.